# how can i get the value '111'

Tags: python

```
def a():
    w='www'
a.a='aaa'
print a.__dict__
a.__dict__={'1':'111','2':'222'}
print a.1#error
print a['1']#error
```

how can i get the value '111'
thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this to yourself?

Comment: see django.utils.functional.py

Comment: please, don't do it. `__dict__` is not what it seems and is not guaranteed to be defined for any object (for example, check this: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Just use setattr. Please. Oh, and `1` is not a valid identifier in python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to do

```
print a.__dict__['1']
```

or

```
print getattr(a, '1')
```

"1" is not a valid variable name in Python. If you did:

```
a.__dict__ = {'a1' : '111'}
print a.a1
```

it would work.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend messing with `__dict__` though. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you say are just a beginner, perhaps you're just looking for the even easier:

```
 a = {'1':'111','2':'222'}
```

so `a['1']` returns the desired `'111'`

Answer (score 1):

You can access it thanks to the `__dict__` member. See following code

```
def a():
    w='www'
a.a='aaa'
print a.__dict__
a.__dict__={'1':'111','2':'222'}
print a.__dict__['1']
```